# Trouble using jquery serialize() on modal form

Tags: html, jquery, css

When using a Bootstrap 4 modal with several forms separately displayed or hidden, the form field names are changed to random values.
From Google Chrome Devtools - Form Source:

```
<div>
  <label for="YoB">Birth Year</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="YoB" placeholder="YoB (approx)">
</div>
```

From Google Chrome Devtools - Elements:

```
<form id="AWForm2" class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;">
<div>
  <label for="YoB">Birth Year</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ryfdlthwhsn" placeholder="YoB (approx)">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="process()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> SEARCH NAMES</button>

function process() {
      var saveDat = $("#AWForm2").serialize();
}
```

When entering 1985 into the form input element and clicking the button, the result is:
`"ryfdlthwhsn=1985"`

It appears that the DOM has changed with the input name being altered.
Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can programatically obtain the value of the input with name 'YoB'.
Note that the DOM is visible in the modal when the button is clicked.

Comment: Do you think you could whip up a reproducible example using a StackSnippet in your question (or jsFiddle)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/69oby8Ld/

Comment: Working on a snippet for jsFiddle - let you know when it is ready.